# Insert a unique value to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table named `leads` with one column named `id`, it is not a primary key and not auto incremented. I want to take the maximum id and increment it to insert new id. 
 This is my approach.
(I do this for testing)

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<1000; $i++){

    \DB::beginTransaction();
    \DB::raw('LOCK TABLES leads WRITE');
    // Get maximum id
    $max = (int)\DB::table('leads')->max('id');

    \DB::table('leads')->insert([
        'id'=>str_pad(++$max, 10, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT) // Make 10 digit id
    ]);

    \DB::raw('UNLOCK TABLES');
    \DB::commit();

}
?>
```

When I execute this code at once, the id does not being duplicate. But when I hit this route from multiple browser at a time, the id gets duplicate. How can I resolve the problem without make the column AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: Why can't you use AUTO_INCREMENT? That way works, it has better performance, and and supports concurrent inserts.

Comment: If you need unique you have several alternatives, make id primary key, make id unique index, or the best from my point of view which in your case avoid calculate last record which can be reach by `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`; in your case, but if you could change the type of id to UUID you could `SELECT UUID()`; which give you an unique value for each record without any more checks

Comment: You should read about [how table locks and transactions interact with each other](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#lock-tables-and-transactions) - your code probably isn't doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `AUTO_INCREMENT`. but if you don't want you can insert multi record to avoid duplicate same as :

```
<?php

\DB::beginTransaction();
// Get maximum id
$max = (int)\DB::table('leads')->max('id');
\DB::raw('LOCK TABLES leads WRITE');
for($i=1; $i<1000; $i++){
    $data[] = [
        'id'=>str_pad(++$max, 10, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT) // Make 10 digit id
    ]
}
\DB::table('leads')->insert($data);
\DB::raw('UNLOCK TABLES');
\DB::commit();
?>
```

I think it's best to use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, locking the table in this case will degrade performance and cause some unwanted effects.
If you want the same format as str_pad, you can use laravel's [Defining A Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)